# How to get app version on Windows Phone Universal App?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to use Assembly to get app version, but it doesn't have GetExecutingAssembly() method on Universal App, how can I do it?

```
string version = "V " + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get through to the assembly via reflection:

```
string version = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Version.ToString(4);
```

(from [Chris Sienkiewicz's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chris/archive/2013/02/14/getting-the-assembly-file-version.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the following to get the version string for a Windows 10 Universal App:

```
var version =
    Application
    .Current
    .GetType()
    .AssemblyQualifiedName
    .Split(' ')[2]
    .Split('=')[1]
    .Replace(",", "");
```